# Sublime: previosuly searched/replaced items

Tags: replace, sublimetext2

I am a Sublime's newbie and I am trying to use the cool Find/replace tab. 
Is there a way (package or shortcut) to have a scroll-down menu that shows items I previously searched/replaced? This feature is available for example in Notepad++. This would be particularly helpful hen working with regex's variations.

I searched and found question about running a series of search-replaces in a row but what I need is just the possibility to go back to items I looked for in the past.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Sublime 3, this feature is available.  Below is a screenshot (underneath the window you see on the right is a drop-down arrow).  Are you using Sublime 2 or 3? Sublime Text 3 can be downloaded [here](http://www.sublimetext.com/3).

[image: Find Drop-Down]

Comment: Thanks, yes I am using version 2. Thanks for the info.